# Ember setting a route model to an object from an array of models

Tags: ember.js

Im trying to set a model for a nested route based on the parents array of models.

```
Msmapp.ClassroomStudentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({  
  model: function(params) {
    return this.modelFor('classroom').get('classroomStudents');
  }
});

Msmapp.ClassroomStudentsStudentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var studentObjects = this.modelFor('classroom_students'),
        studentObject = null;

        studentObjects.forEach(function(student) {
          if (student.get('id') == params.student_id) {
               studentObject = student;
          }
        });

   return studentObject;
  }
});
```

Normally when navigating into this route its fine because im passing along the model, but if I try to copy/paste the url or refresh the page from this point where it has to hit the router i dont get anything.

If I console log studentObject.toString() i can see that its  It appears the im returning an Msmapp.Student object so im not sure what im missing or may need to do to get this to work.

These are my routes

```
this.resource('classrooms', function() {
    this.resource('classroom', {path: ':classroom_id'}, function() {
        this.route('new_student');
        this.resource('classroom_students', function() {
            this.route('student', {path: ':student_id'})
        });
        this.route('new_assignment');
        this.resource('classroom_assignments', function() {
            this.route('assignment', {path: ':assignment_id'})
        });
    });
    this.route('new');
});
```

and this initial request for the student objects comes back in the JSON for the classroom.

The classroomStudents is a computed property that loops the student objects and creates an Msmapp.Student object for each one.

Also if I change the route to be Msmapp.ClassroomStudent it works, but its making a request to the server for the object. Then i end up with 2 different instances of the same object, when all i really need is to be able to grab the object from the already setup array of objects.